# How can I validate the request user in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am sending a update request like:

```
Route::put('user/{user}/edit-user-education', 'UpdateUserEducationController@editUserEducation');
```

**My controller is :**

```
class UpdateUserEducationController extends Controller
{
    public function editUserEducation(UserEducation $education, User $user, EditUserEducationRequest $request)
    {
        $education->school = $request->school;
        $education->degree = $request->degree;
        $education->user_id = $user->id;  // here to validate

  
        $education->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Education Updated'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now how I can validate the request user_id with the user_id already in inserted in DB ? I want to ensure that the only user can update the record who created that one.

How to do so ? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use policy for authorization, for more detail: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the docs on validation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation

Specifically, I think you want the `exists` rule:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exists

The quick and dirty way is to add your validation in the controller but there are some better methods as explained in the docs. I usually opt for Form Requests, which it looks like you've already done as your request is an instance of `EditUserEducationRequest`.

In the controller you can add:

```
$validated = $EditUserEducationRequest->validate([
    'user_id' => 'required|exists:users',
]);
```

I assume your user table is called `users`.

You could alternatively state the `exists` validation rule for `user_id` in the `rules` array of your Form Request as per the docs.

EDIT:

I actually missed a requirement in your original post that is that the user sending the request must be the same user as the one being updated.
That can be handled in the the `authorize` method of your form request with something like:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return $this->user()->id == $this->user_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply make a check that current user is the same user who is trying to update record.

```
class UpdateUserEducationController extends Controller
{
    public function editUserEducation(UserEducation $education, User $user, EditUserEducationRequest $request)
    {
        if($user->id==Auth::user()->id){
            $education->school = $request->school;
            $education->degree = $request->degree;
            $education->user_id = $user->id;  // here to validate

  
            $education->save();

            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Education Updated'
            ]);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Invalid User'
            ]);
        } 
    }
}
```